# I can't install PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, homebrew

I want to install PyQt4. I've tried everything that I could find: use my command line, use brew. Nothing seems to work!

If would be really useful if someone could explain everything from step one, if necessary reinstalling python. I'm quite new to installing files from source and I'm not sure whether I'm in the correct path or have all the files needed when I tell my terminal to install pyqt4 like this:

```
brew install pyqt
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching for it... There is a `pyqt5` that you can install from brew, but no `pyqt4`.

```
$ brew search pyqt 
pyqt5
```

In other words, if you need PyQt4, you have to find other resources, like going to a download page, and getting it.